# Way to create indexedDB index in IDBObjectSore with keyPath like this: 'location:location._id'

Tags: indexeddb

I have some data in an indexedDB store that looks like this:

```
{
    "assetNo" : "00045455",
    "location:location" : {
        "title" : "19100003BRMA2879",
        "_id" : "5e2727cbc38a923f5826efb7"
    }
}
```

I'd like to create an index on the _id inside that location, but it seems like indexedDB does not like that colon in between location:location.  I'm getting an error: 
*DOMException: Failed to execute 'createIndex' on 'IDBObjectStore': The keyPath argument contains an invalid key path*

The colon is a convention that is used through thousands and thousands of lines of code, so just changing it would be a problem.  Is there some way around this?  A way to escape the colon for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB-2/#key-path-construct I see that it states that:

> A valid key path is one of:
>
> - An empty string.
> - An identifier, which is a string matching the IdentifierName production from the ECMAScript Language Specification [ECMA-262].
> - A string consisting of two or more identifiers separated by periods (U+002E FULL STOP).
> - A non-empty list containing only strings conforming to the above requirements.
>
> Spaces are not allowed within a key path.

Looks like the colon violates the second bullet point.

Would it be ok for you to change the data as it is written to and read from the database? This is a pretty common thing to occur when storing data, sometimes you need to modify what is actually persisted.

Something like:

```js
function write(db, object) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const transaction = db.transaction('mystore', 'readwrite');
    transaction.oncomplete = resolve;
    transaction.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    const store = transaction.objectStore('mystore');

    // what i am suggesting, modify just before write
    // the extra cloning is to avoid side effects on input

    const clone = { ...object };
    clone.location_location = clone['location:location'];
    delete clone['location:location'];

    store.put(clone);    
  });
}

function onupgradeneeded(event) {
  const db = event.target.result;
  const store = db.createObjectStore('mystore');
  db.createIndex('location_id', 'location_location._id');
}

function getByLocationId(db, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const transaction = db.transaction('mystore');
    const store = transaction.objectStore('mystore');
    const index = store.index('location_id');
    const request = index.get(id);
    request.onerror = event => reject(request.error);
    request.onsuccess = event => {
      const result = event.target.result;
      // if we found something, project output as if we stored 
      // it with a colon. we do not need to clone here.
      if (result) {
        result['location:location'] = result.location_location;
        delete result.location_location;
      }
      resolve(result);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Last night after submitting the question, I started thinking along the same lines.  It was really kind of you to write the actual code.  Great answer.